# Find all posts associated with a tag in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am building a blog with laravel where a post has many tags. I want to filter all post by a tag. means if I click on "PHP" tag I want to get all associated post.

**Here is my code**

I have two table first for tags and a second table for the link with posts

**tag_table**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('tags');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**relation tag table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('article_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles');
      $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags');
    });
}
```

**Article Model**

```
class Article extends Model
{
 public function tags()
 {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
 }
}
```

**tag model**

```
class Tag extends Model
{
  public function articles()
 {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article');
 }
}
```

**Tag Controller**

```
 public function show($id,$name)
{
   //here I received tag id and name.

 $list->with('articles')->get();
 return view('articles.tagshow')->withList($list);

}
```

Comment: have you read eloquent relationship. If not then i recommend reading it, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eloquent offers the **whereHas** method that lets you filter on attributes of related models. In order to filter articles by the name of their associated tags, you should do the following:

```
$articles = Article::whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tagName) {
  $query->whereName($tagName);
})->get();
```

However, in your case it should be even simpler, because you already have the tag ID in your controller, so you can simply get a tag model by ID and then return related articles:

```
public function show($id,$name) {
  return Tag::findOrFail($id)->articles;
}
```

Check the docs on querying relations for more details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations